# Error with rosinstall

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I tried to download and install our entire robot package today, and I got this for every package svn tried to checkout:
..." : checkout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'"

This is the command that I ran:
rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/electric ~/ros/electric-deb.rosinstall
where electric-deb.rosinstall is:

```
- other:
    local-name: /opt/ros/electric/ros
- other:
    local-name: /opt/ros/electric/stacks

- svn:
    uri: https://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arrg
    local-name: ua-ros-pkg

- svn:
    uri: https://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk
    local-name: stacks/erratic_robot
- svn:
    uri: https://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/dynamixel_motor/trunk
    local-name: stacks/dynamixel_motor

- svn:
    uri: http://foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/phidgets/phidgetspp_c_api
    local-name: foote-ros-pkg/phidgets/phidgetspp_c_api
- svn:
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/camera_drivers_experimental
    local-name: stacks/camera_drivers_experimental

- svn:
    uri: https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/openrave_planning
    local-name: jsk-ros-pkg/openrave_planning
- svn:
    uri: https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/jsk_common
    local-name: jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_common

- svn:
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_release/trunk
    local-name: stacks/ros_release
- svn:
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/release/trunk
    local-name: release
```

Can anyone help please?
Thanks,
-Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32503/error-with-rosinstall/) by [nfaction](https://answers.ros.org/users/2239/nfaction/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make sure that rosinstall and vcstools are up to date.

`sudo pip install -U vcstools rosinstall`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1